# How to reduce the taste of tomato in a tomato sauce?

Tags: sauce, indian-cuisine, tomatoes

I did butter chicken for the first time. It was good but I felt that the tomato sauce had too much tomato flavour.

The sauce was made of tomato passata and liquid cream (and what remained from the marinade of the chicken, it was very little).

**What should I do to reduce the taste of tomatoes?** (it is a bit too present compared to what I get in Indian restaurants, and my personal taste as well).

Comment: There's a heck of a lot of variation in the recipes for that, even in Indian restaurants. I've had it where it tastes like chicken tikka in Heinz tomato soup, with some 'curry'.

Comment: Passata is a traditional Italian product and is somewhat concentrated by cooking the tomatoes before sieving, and then bottling. It has a fairly concentrated tomato flavour, but it's not as thick as a concentrated tomato purée (aka tomato paste). You could perhaps use less of it, or just use a can of chopped tomatoes instead, which won't be so concentrated, even perhaps some fresh tomatoes.

Comment: Buy tomatoes picked green and shipped a long way that have no flavor at all to start with? ;^)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm sorry, I only have these uselessly flavorous local ripe tomatoes at the market. Yes, it is a shame, I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should look for a different recipe or tomato component.

After a quick look around, I found some differences in the tomato components used. Some recipes are using passata, some are using tomato purees and some chopped canned tomatoes.

So if you feel there is too much tomato, I'd suggest trying chopped tomatoes either canned or fresh.
If it tastes not tomatoy enough you could add tomato puree or passata step for step until you achieve the desired tomato taste.